# Diode populated keyboard matrix: Wire two separate buttons to the same output?

Tags: switches, output, input, keyboard, matrix

I have an encoder board for a 16x8 row/column switch matrix.
An absolute beginner to electronics but using all of the great online resources for research the best I can. However, occasionally it turns out to be surprisingly difficult to find an answer to something very specific.

As a reference from the manufacturer distributed user manual, the traditional diode populated wiring diagram can be seen on page 4: [User manual](http://xkeys.com/assets/manuals/XK-0988-UNM128.1088UK.pdf)

I illustrated my question to sum up what I'm asking:
[image: Illustrated question]

Comment: Page 5 tells you how to use connector J6 to simply connect up to 3 switches. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Need to get right to the point to the question; too much background info. Basically, you have a 16x8 key matrix with diodes, and you want two buttons in that matrix to do the same thing (for example a left shift and right shift key)? If yes, then just wire the two keys in parallel. Or was it more complicated than that?

Comment: @SteveG No, I will actually using the entire matrix, plenty of switches.

Comment: @VincePatron Yes indeed. Not just two buttons, but a lot of them. For example, say I have 10 different actions mapped to 10 different switchpoints on the matrix. If I want to make two separate physical button panels that do exactly the same thing, I'd want them to be able to connect to the same 10 switchpoints on the matrix. Using up a total of 20 switchpoints just to program the identical sets of 10 actions twice is a waste of matrix space. As a real life example that we all know, the duplicate shift keys or ctrl keys are a great example.